# Csv blank rows problem with Excel

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have a csv file which contains rows from a sqlite3 database. I wrote the rows to the csv file using python.

When I open the csv file with Ms Excel, a blank row appears below every row, but the file on notepad is fine(without any blanks).

Does anyone know why this is happenning and how I can fix it?

Edit: I used the strip() function for all the attributes before writing a row.

Thanks.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You're using `open('file.csv', 'w')`--try `open('file.csv', 'wb')`.

The Python csv module requires output files be opened in binary mode.

Comment: Your solution worked! thank you very much. since csv files are stored as text, I thought i didn't need to add the binary flag. Btw, How did you know I didn't write wb without even looking at the code?

Comment: I had the same problem about a year ago.

Comment: Thanks @robert. Wish I could give you a couple more up votes! I wish the docs made this info a bit easier to find. Relevant section: `If csvfile is a file object, it must be opened with the ‘b’ flag on platforms where that makes a difference.`

Answer (score 0):

the first that comes into my mind (just an idea) is that you might have used "\r\n" as row delimiter (which is shown as one linebrak in notepad) but excel expects to get only "\n" or only "\r" and so it interprets this as two line-breaks.

Comment: hi, i stripped all spaces with the strip() function before writing to the file

Comment: The default/usual/common/expected-by-Excel row (NOT line) terminator for CSV files **is** `\r\n`